# Are there any issue with Parse Twillio Integration since this morning?

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

Parse Twillio cloud code stopped working since last 3 hours. Did someone come across this issue. If so, are there any known solutions.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

We did discover an issue and resolved as you can see in the [twilio-node](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) helper library github repo: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/152

Answer (score -1):

Yes it seems to be an SSL issue. Multiple reports have been submitted to Parse.

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1696266953962575/

Update:

The issue has been resolved for now but according to Facebook's technician, Hector, the root cause of the problem is the root CA used for api.twilio.com's SSL cert was dropped from Mozilla's cert bundle. Twilio is aware of the issue and will be switching certificates soon.

Comment: FB Tech are on it now it seems:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1696266953962575/